# Threading in .NET core ASP Controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, .net-core

I've made a clean project of .net Core 3.0 Web application and I am trying to understand, how `ThreadPool` works in C#.

```
namespace TestASPSelf.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

        public static int countThread = 0;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {

            int workerThreads;
            int portThreads;

            ThreadPool.GetMaxThreads(out workerThreads, out portThreads);
            Console.WriteLine("\nMaximum worker threads: \t{0}" +
                              "\nMaximum completion port threads: {1}",
                workerThreads, portThreads);

            ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads(out workerThreads,
                out portThreads);
            Console.WriteLine("\nAvailable worker threads: \t{0}" +
                              "\nAvailable completion port threads: {1}\n",
                workerThreads, portThreads);    

                Console.WriteLine("countThread = " + countThread);

            return View();
        }

        class Z
        {
            public static void WaitTest(object o)
            {
                countThread++;
                while (true)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }
            }
        }

        public IActionResult Privacy()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("starting thread "+i);
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(Z.WaitTest));
            }

            return View();
        }
}
}
```

When http://localhost:5000/Home/Privacy opened, it hangs for some time (for about 40-80 seconds), but I see, that logic of `for` cycles in it completes almost instantly.
When http://localhost:5000/ opened after that, it hangs for 40-80 seconds too and result is in console `countThread = 100`.
CPU usage of app is about 5-10%, when threads were started.

I am trying to understand:

1) The first one is why ASP controller hangs for 40-80 seconds per page, when 100 Threads are running by CPU usage 5-10 percents. CPU has a lot of resources, RAM is free too, but why ASP Controller methods of pages are hangs?

2) How to create ThreadPool in C# with limited count of running threads? If I understand method `public static bool SetMinThreads (int workerThreads, int completionPortThreads);` correctly, it affects globally all threads of the app. How to create object of ThreadPool with limited count of active threads, like `ExecutorService` in Java? For example, Java code of thread pool could look like

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Runnable worker = new WorkerThread("" + i);
            executor.execute(worker);
          }
        executor.shutdown();
        while (!executor.isTerminated()) {
        }
```

3) How to prevent hangs of all methods of ASP Controller and to make "truly real" threads, like in Java?

Comment: Don't think in Java, when developing in C#. To achieve the desired behavior, there are several ways. Just forget what you know of Java and look for how you can achieve what you want in C#. For example, you could fire up n Threads yourself, you could use DataFlow with maxParallelism set, just to name 2.

Comment: asp.net is itself a multi-threaded environment: every request has its own thread

Comment: To Fildor: as result, I've solved the task using this tutorial - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-specify-the-degree-of-parallelism-in-a-dataflow-block . Thank you for idea of using DataFlow. Can you please write an answer about DataFlow, I'll mark answer as correct?

Answer (score 0):

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(Z.WaitTest));
```

With this you do something very wrong.  You cause threads in the threadpool to block and thus the pool is unable to finish processing your request and process new requests.

At some point a thread from the pool manages to return and process your next request, but than it hangs again due to the overloaded pool.

As for your other questions, please explain what you want to achieve.  Your question seems to try to solve a problem that is not understood well.

---

**Update**: After Arthur's comment.

If you will be downloading files, you should use Tasks and async-await.  IO operations do not consume threads (more [here](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html)).

Create N tasks, each downloading a file, and then await Task.WhenAll.  Pseudo code:

```
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
for (int i = 0; i < filesToDownloadCount; i++)
{
   var t = new Task ( () => { /* ... code to download your file here ... */});
   tasks.Add (t);
}
await t.WhenAll (tasks);
```

This approach will give you the best throughput and your bottleneck will be your bandwidth, not the CPU.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In my scenarios I am using Threads to make web-requests, not CPU-heavy. I see, that ThreadPool can run about 32000 threads at a time, but I need to limit requests max to 4 threads at a time. So, `public IActionResult Privacy()` initializes a pool of threads, each of them is a method to download file. The list of files is dynamical and I need some object like `ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);` to pass thread to it at any time, as file links was found.

Comment: Each thread has costs - 1 MB of stack as minimum.  Running 32K threads means losing 32GB RAM.   I updated my answer to reflect your comment.

Answer (score 0):

> The ThreadPool class has several static methods including the QueueUserWorkItem that is responsible for calling a thread pool worker thread when it is available. If no worker thread is available in the thread pool, it waits until the thread becomes available.

```
using System;  
using System.Threading;  

class ThreadPoolSample  
{  
    // Background task   
    static void BackgroundTask(Object stateInfo)  
    {  
        Console.WriteLine("Hello! I'm a worker from ThreadPool");  
        Thread.Sleep(1000);          
    }  

    static void BackgroundTaskWithObject(Object stateInfo)  
    {  
        Person data = (Person)stateInfo;          
        Console.WriteLine($"Hi {data.Name} from ThreadPool.");  
        Thread.Sleep(1000);  
    }  
    static void Main(string[] args)  
    {  
        // Use ThreadPool for a worker thread        
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(BackgroundTask);  
        Console.WriteLine("Main thread does some work, then sleeps.");  
        Thread.Sleep(500);  

        // Create an object and pass it to ThreadPool worker thread  
        Person p = new Person("Mahesh Chand", 40, "Male");  
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(BackgroundTaskWithObject, p);  

        int workers, ports;  

        // Get maximum number of threads  
        ThreadPool.GetMaxThreads(out workers, out ports);  
        Console.WriteLine($"Maximum worker threads: {workers} ");  
        Console.WriteLine($"Maximum completion port threads: {ports}");  

        // Get available threads  
        ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads(out workers, out ports);  
        Console.WriteLine($"Availalbe worker threads: {workers} ");  
        Console.WriteLine($"Available completion port threads: {ports}");  

        // Set minimum threads  
        int minWorker, minIOC;  
        ThreadPool.GetMinThreads(out minWorker, out minIOC);  
        ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(4, minIOC);  

        // Get total number of processes availalbe on the machine  
        int processCount = Environment.ProcessorCount;  
        Console.WriteLine($"No. of processes available on the system: {processCount}");  

        // Get minimum number of threads  
        ThreadPool.GetMinThreads(out workers, out ports);  
        Console.WriteLine($"Minimum worker threads: {workers} ");  
        Console.WriteLine($"Minimum completion port threads: {ports}");  

        Console.ReadKey();  
    }  

        // Create a Person class  
        public class Person  
        {  
            public string Name { get; set; }  
            public int Age { get; set; }  
            public string Sex { get; set; }  

            public Person(string name, int age, string sex)  
            {  
                this.Name = name;  
                this.Age = age;  
                this.Sex = sex;  
            }  
        }  
}
```